# The transaction will throw an exception with the current values

Tags: wallets, ico

Trying to do the Status ICO, and when entering in the ether address, I get this warning.  A friend has tried this with another wallet and said he's getting an error/exception and his transaction did not go through.  Any ideas what's going on? Even if I set the "Send after BLockNumber" condition the exception message does not go away.  note that the BlockNumber has already passed.

[image]

Edit:  I tried sending, and got this

> Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Bad instruction]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transaction caused contract execution that would lead to some kind of 'invalid' condition.

In the case of the status ICO, there are two likely causes:

1. The sale had already reached its cap, so when you sent funds, it caused an error on [this line](https://github.com/status-im/status-network-token/blob/master/contracts/StatusContribution.sol#L262):

   ```
   assert(totalCollected() <= failSafeLimit);
   ```

This is most likely, and Parity probably detected this even before you tried to send.

2. You tried to include too much gas, which cause an error on [this line](https://github.com/status-im/status-network-token/blob/master/contracts/StatusContribution.sol#L216):

   ```
   require(tx.gasprice <= maxGasPrice);
   ```

For a bit of extra context, `assert` and `require` are similar. They will cause the transaction to fail, your ETH send will be refunded, but all of the gas you pay for will be used up.

Comment: If it's reached it's cap, then how are transactions still going throw every second?

So here's a recent transaction (someone else) that's currently pending.  Notice it doesn't say "Contract" next to the "To:", did I send it incorrectly?
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x3c39e19a2e29640ffef90079a1ad6b153205bc32e40a497b16f8135739f39fb0

Here was mine which got rejected: 
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x32b2803a1826b20f3ea255a05b6b70500847e7e0eab9306720b65d9ecf077fcd

Comment: I have no idea why people are still sending, but that transaction will ultimately have the same fate as yours. Ie. it was sent way too late, and will eventually be rejected in the same way.

Comment: Yeah I see.  I'm looking at recent transactions and once they get about a minute old they get flagged as such. This one doesn't seem to be yet though.  This one from 6 minutes ago went through... I don't really understand why it worked. https://etherscan.io/tx/0x0c846eb5ac13bebcaecaaec2b51d7ff64d0604823dc7f2776ebd4f82b87241f6

Comment: Looks like that one went through in the end. Could you upvote and accept my initial answer, I think it was sufficient for the original question.

Comment: Yes, your answer is correct.  That tx referenced wasn't mine.  It was someone else's that worked around the time I sent mine.